# JsonPath: filter by value in any array in array

Tags: java, arrays, json, filter, jsonpath

I try to filter to get value from subscriberNumber inside "*..ou.subscriber" that have extendedinfo[SOURCE_OR_TARGET=="TARGET"], but my jsonpath its doesn't work.

**The jsonpath I try:**

```
$..ou[?(@.extendedInfo[0].value=="TARGET")].subscriber[0].subscriberNumber
```

The result, I would like to get this subscriberNumber = "001"

**The JSON:**

```
    {
    "customer": {
        "customerId": "34975213",
        "ou": [
            {
                "numberOfIDD": 0,
                "numberOfIR": 0,
                "ouId": 117482315,
                "subscriber": [
                    {
                        "status": 0,
                        "subscriberId": "90674393",
                        "subscriberNumber": "001"
                    }
                ],
                "responseCode": "FM120100000",
                "responseMsg": "Success",
                "extendedInfo": [
                    {
                        "name": "SOURCE_OR_TARGET",
                        "value": "BUCKET"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "SOURCE_OR_TARGET",
                        "value": "TARGET"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "numberOfIDD": 0,
                "numberOfIR": 0,
                "ouId": 21046276,
                "subscriber": [
                    {
                        "status": 65,
                        "subscriberId": "17404432",
                        "subscriberNumber": "002"
                    }
                ],
                "extendedInfo": [
                    {
                        "name": "SOURCE_OR_TARGET",
                        "value": "SOURCE"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

bad design data structure you want filter for subscriber node with extendedInfo but not include it in subscriber

Comment: The data structure came from legacy system. I can't control and improve them.